# Samba Configuration

Tags: installation, 12.10, samba

I am having a problem when configuring samba

I manage to login to samba and create a folder and configure it t share.

I can see the the folder on my windows machine but when trying to click in it it says that i have no permissions

I have added acess to all users on samba config

should i try to remove and re-install samba? if so would be the command?

could it be an issue with the actual drive permission that the folder is at?

When i try to do it from the GUI in Ubunutu(bypassing samba) i get error net usershar:cannot pen usershare directory error permition denied

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: can you provide the file permission on the shared folder? 

ls -lrt <folder_name>

The folder should have read+execute permission for group and others.

Comment: what is the command t check that? :/

Comment: sorry you already mentioned above o will check

Comment: change the permission of the folder to 775.

chmod 775 <directory_name> . It should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A share-config in smb.conf can look like this.

```
[share]
path = /opt/share
valid users = <user>
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
readable = yes
writable = yes
browseable = yes
```

Did you added and enabled the user?

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <user>
sudo smbpasswd -e <user>
```

Make sure both processes "smbd" and "nmbd" are running:

```
sudo ps axu | grep smbd
sudo ps axu | grep nmbd
```

Comment: how do i completely uninstall  the samba so i can re-install

Comment: this is what i get when i run sudo ps axu command   
1000      8662  0.0  0.0   4396   832 pts/7    S+   21:13   0:00 grep --color=auto smbd

Comment: i think the best option is to un install and re install. if so do i have to reboot the server?

Comment: i have used the purge command and now got rid of samba however the files still on /etc/samba there are 3 files there... sh ould that have not been removed as well with the unintall

Comment: I manage to re-install samba but when i run the command rpm -qa | grep samba i do not get any output also if i try sudo apt-get install samba i get the following output root@22cansSRV1:~# sudo apt-get install samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
samba is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

Comment: rpm is for Redhat based distros and apt-get is for debian based distros like ubuntu. So rm can't work. I think samba is working correctly and is still installed how you can see. It is a permissions issue in my opinion. If you want to uninstall and delete alle configuration use `sudo apt-get purge samba`

Comment: The problem is that when i Purge samba, samba files remians there. the when i re-install the same files are there so for instance if i purge now the sbm.conf file does not get changed to a newfile. is there a way to get rid of everything even the files?

Comment: Hmm, purge is there to remove all files related to the software package. But samba is only configured in the smb.conf so you can delete it manually. You can also do a `dpkg --list | grep smb` or `dpkg --list | grep samba` to see all the packes which are still installed. `dpkg --purge <package>` will remove the packages if there are no errors. But be carefull, you can damage your system with this step. apt-get ist the safer way to uninstall.

Comment: that is what i get when i run your command

Comment: ii  libpam-smbpass:i386                       2:3.6.6-3ubuntu5                          i386         pluggable authentication module for Samba

Comment: what does it mean

Comment: and if i run this commandt dpkg --list | grep samba i get

Comment: rc  samba                                     2:3.6.6-3ubuntu5                          i386         SMB/CIFS file, print, and login server for Unix
ii  samba-common                              2:3.6.6-3ubuntu5                          all          common files used by both the Samba server and client
ii  samba-common-bin                          2:3.6.6-3ubuntu5                          i386         common files used by both the Samba server and client

Comment: I got it. i have un install and re-install. used the above guide and made minor changed on the smb.conf file and it is working